# How can i get the values of each cell of table using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table where I can drag and drop elements, and I want to save the table and then display the table with all the values saved on that indexes only as was saved from db.
I am able to get index of columns and rows. but i am facing challenge in identifying the approach for how to set the values at particular index as was saved.

Table structure is like I get the inputs for the number of input,outputcolumns and rows from user. So I create the table according to the input.. that's why i have taken three separate arrays for input_column, output_column and rows. also need to add some validations so taken separate drop method for drop on input and output header.

This is my controller.js

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.buttons = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
      $scope.tableSelection = {};
      $scope.tableInputColSelection={};
    $scope.tableOutputColSelection={};
    $scope.output_columns=[1];
    $scope.input_columns=[1];
      $scope.data = [];
      $scope.rows = [1, 2, 3]; 

      $scope.removeSelectedItems = function(){
       // $scope.rows = $scope.rows.filter(function(item, index){
         // return !($scope.tableSelection[index] !== undefined && $scope.tableSelection[index]); 
       if(Object.keys($scope.tableSelection).length>0){
                                 for (var i = $scope.rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                                  if ($scope.tableSelection[i]) {
                                    //delete row from data
                                      if($scope.rows.length>1){
                                      $scope.rows.splice(i, 1);
                                      }

                                     delete $scope.tableSelection[i];
                                }
                                 }
                                }
                                if(Object.keys($scope.tableInputColSelection).length>0){
                                    for (var i = $scope.input_columns.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                                      if ($scope.tableInputColSelection[i]) {
                                        //delete row from data
                                          if($scope.input_columns.length>1){
                                            $scope.input_columns.splice(i, 1);
                                          }
                                        delete $scope.tableInputColSelection[i];
                                      }
                                }

                                }
                                if(Object.keys($scope.tableOutputColSelection).length>0){
                                    for (var i = $scope.output_columns.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                                      if ($scope.tableOutputColSelection[i]) {
                                        //delete row from data
                                          if($scope.output_columns.length>1){
                                            $scope.output_columns.splice(i, 1);
                                          }
                                        delete $scope.tableOutputColSelection[i];
                                      }
                                    }
                                }





      }
      $scope.addNewRow = function() {
        //set row selected if is all checked

        $scope.rows.push({
          id: $scope.rows.length,
          name: 'Name ' + $scope.rows.length
        });
      };
     $scope.addInput= function () {
                                for(var i=0;i<1;i++){
                                    $scope.input_columns.push({
                                        id:$scope.input_columns.length,
                                        name: 'Name'+$scope.input_columns.length
                                    });
                                    }
                            },

         $scope.addOutput= function () {
                                for(var i=0;i<1;i++){
                                    $scope.output_columns.push({
                                        id:$scope.output_columns.length,
                                        name:'Name'+$scope.output_columns.length
                                    });
                                    }
                            }


     $scope.handleDragEnd = function(e) {
            //debugger
            this.style.opacity = '1.0';
          };

          $scope.handleDragOver = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
            e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move'; // See the section on the DataTransfer object.
            return false;
          };
          $scope.handleHeaderDrop = function(e,item,index) {
             debugger
              var path = undefined;
              item.dropped=true;
              var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
             e.target.innerHTML = data;
              e.preventDefault();
              e.stopPropagation();
              e.target.id=path; 


          };
           $scope.handleHeaderDropOutput = function(e,item,index) {
                  debugger
                  var path = undefined;
                  item.dropped=true;
                  var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
                  e.target.innerHTML = data;
                  e.target.id=path;
                  e.preventDefault();
                  e.stopPropagation();

                };

    $scope.drag=  function (ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.path[0].innerText);
        $scope.rhsContentProvider = new TreeContentProviderForXMI($scope.currentDictionaryModel.rhsDataDictionary);

    };
    $scope.allowDrop= function (ev) {
        if(ev!=false)
        ev.preventDefault();
    };
    $scope.drop=  function (ev,item,indx) {
    debugger
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.stopPropagation();
        var path = undefined;//CCGBASE-2218 changes
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");

    };
    });
```

I have added the plunker for full code. though I am not able to set the values of button which I have dropped on table cell.
Here i want that what approach i should follow to get all the values which i have dropped on each cell for setting the table again with the same values when fetching data from db.

Plunker-
http://plnkr.co/edit/MB2icqN9csG7RmJVMhyL?p=preview

Comment: You can do following: When you're dragging a value to a cell, add that value to the `data` attribute of the cell too. For example, you can set the attribute data-value='the-dropped-value' when a value is dropped over a specific cell. Later on, while saving it to db, you can retrieve these value using jQuery's `$.data()` or simply plain javascript!

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this using angular. Also how can i get the sequence in which the values were dropped, so that while fetching data I can identify where to place that data in the table cell

Comment: with seperate header array I am able to get the values dropped in input column header and output column header. But I am not getting how to get values of each cell of rows sequentially

Comment: Yes. The simpler way would be to assign an `id` to each cell in format `cell0_1`, `cell0_2'...,`cell1_1`, and so on. Now, using plain javascript, you can retrieve the data attribute values. Also, to keep a track of sequence, you can use a hidden input wherein you can append the index of the cell (or even it's ID) so as to know, in what sequence were these values changed

Comment: the table which i am creating is with the combination of input column, output column and rows. So the column made on the basis of input and output colum entered value and same with row.. So here the challenge i face is to how to get each cell value..that's why i am not able to add an id to each cell. can you suggest something how can i add id to each cell with this scenario.

Comment: Well, in that case, you can use timestamp to assign id to a cell!